# Cocos2D Accelerometer Z axis

Tags: sprites, cocos2d-iphone, ios, cocos2d, ccsprite

I am making a 2D scroller game where the player controls an airplane via the accelerometer  I would like to know if it is possible to scale in and to scale out the sprite/airplane using the accelerometer z axis. I would like to know how to do this to create a depth illusion.

Any suggestion, tutorial recommendation, and comments are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can access the Z data from the accelerometer just like you would access the X and Y data.

Sample cocos2d projects show how to use the accelerometer; in a nutshell, you will have a method as follows in the CCLayer subclass that controls your game:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer*)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration*)acceleration
{   
    NSLog(@"Accelerometer z value is %f\n", acceleration.z);
}
```

Keep in mind that the accelerometer only detects *acceleration* - it might be a bit tricky for you to achieve exactly the desired effect. For a depth effect graphics-wise, you might want to look into parallalax scrolling.

Comment: How would I use the parallax effect to do this trick? I mean I am using this effect for static objects such as the ground,rocks and such but I never thought of using it on a moving sprite. I am sorry I could not find a video to show you what I mean so to better explain myself just take your hand, face it towards you and just zoom it in and out the effect that you saw is the effect I would like to apply to my airplane using the accelerometer z axis however I don't know if this is possible. Thanks for responding.